# How can we get the path/url of the custom folder created in the iphone/ipad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, alassetslibrary

I am storing some videos in the custom folder which is created with the help of Alasset library in device . Videos are storing in custom folder successfully. I want to get the path / url of that particular folder.

Can someone tell me the way to get the path/url for the custom folder that we created programmatically with the help of Alasset library.

I search a lot about this.But google always provide solution with document directory. I don't want the path of document directory. But the path of actual folder created in my device. This problem takes my so much of time to solve. Please  someone help me.

Comment: How did you create the path?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

This code will give you the url where the file is stored.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
    if (error) {  
        NSLog(@"error");  
    } else {  
            NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);  
    }  
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply... But this solution is for image. I am asking about videos.
i want to get only the URL, so that i can able to find a particular video is present in that folder or not.

Comment: Try - writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSURL *)videoPathURL completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock

Comment: so in this method what will be the value of (NSURL *)videoPathURL? 
Because When i directly use the video URL given from the server then this function won't work..So in that case what will be the value of (NSURL *)videoPathURL?... This is my real confusion. Please help me.

Comment: Get this from - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];